# Registration form fields reset after submit (wordpress & woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, form-verification

I've got woocommerce registration form with two sections:
 
 - One for private person,
 
 - the other for company.

In company option there is two additional fields. I can switch between private and company by radio buttons and then I see relevant fields.

Problem: When I fill the form (as private user) and make some mistake, form reload and show where is the error (that is ok).

But unfortunately, after reload, it loads the form with all fields (the ones with additional company fields too). So I need to click 2 times between private and company to restore the right behavior.

How can i fix this? I mean after this error reloading, to display the form as initially.

I don't be sure that this is code responsible for this, but let's try:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'rs_registration_form_validation', 10, 3);
function rs_registration_form_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email)
{
    global $woocommerce;

    $company_fields_required = (!empty($_POST['registration_type']) && 'company' === $_POST['registration_type']);
    $shipp_to_different_address = (!empty($_POST['register_ship_to_different_address']) && 1 == $_POST['register_ship_to_different_address']);

    $errors = false;
    $fields = rs_registration_form_fields();
    if ($shipp_to_different_address) {
        $fields += rs_registration_form_fields_address();
    }

    if (!$company_fields_required) {
        unset($fields['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing_nip']);
    }

    //Validate required
    foreach ($fields as $field => $settings) {
        if (false === isset($settings['required']) || true === $settings['required']) {
            if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
                $errors = true;
                wc_add_notice('Pole: <strong>'.$settings['label'].'</strong> jest wymagane.', 'error');
            }
        }
    }

    if ($errors) {
        return new WP_Error('registration-error', 'Proszę poprawić błędy w formularzu');
    }

    return $reg_errors;
}

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'rs_registration_form_submit');
function rs_registration_form_submit($user_id)
{
    $fields = rs_registration_form_fields();
    $fields += rs_registration_form_fields_address();

    foreach ($fields as $field => $settings) {
        if (isset($_POST[$field]) && !empty($_POST[$field])) {
            update_user_meta($user_id, $field, $_POST[$field]);
        }
    }
}

add_filter('register_form', 'rs_registration_form');
function rs_registration_form()
{
    $fields = rs_registration_form_fields();

    include '_rs_registration_form.php';
}

add_filter('register_form_address', 'rs_registration_form_address');
function rs_registration_form_address()
{
    $fields = rs_registration_form_fields_address();

    include '_rs_registration_form.php';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_edit_address_slugs', 'rs_fix_address_slugs');
function rs_fix_address_slugs($slugs)
{
    $slugs['billing'] = 'billing';
    $slugs['shipping'] = 'shipping';

    return $slugs;
}

function rs_rejestracja_url()
{
    return get_permalink(244);
}

function rs_logowanie_url()
{
    return get_permalink(20);
}

function rs_show_checkout_progress_bar($step = '')
{
    include '_checkout_progress_bar.php';
}

function rs_order_form_buttons()
{
    include '_order_form_buttons.php';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'rs_get_checout_url');
function rs_get_checout_url($url) {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $url .= '#step1';
    }

    return $url;
}

include 'src/RS_Search.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know WooCommerce, but I think the error results because of these lines:

```
$company_fields_required = (!empty($_POST['registration_type']) && 'company' === $_POST['registration_type']);
```

and

```
if (!$company_fields_required) {
    unset($fields['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing_nip']);
}
```

After you submitted your "private" form and the validation failed, your fields are loaded again. Could it now be, that in your $_POST variable the registration_type is somehow set to 'company'? You can test this if you just print_r your $_POST['registration_type'] at the beginning of the function. If that is not the case, then I'm pretty sure the bug happens in another function, because this makes sense to me so far.

EDIT: After taking another look on your code, I think none of the posted functions is responsible for the misbehaviour. The first function is only responsible to check if some of the posted values are missing and to say "hey, here is an error". There has to be another function which is responsible for the fields which later are displayed in your HTML. I think you need to find this function.

Comment: ok. Here is a code of registration form template... could you deduce anything from this? http://paste.ofcode.org/rd9Z4VUXjuiEeLBAQnRtxT

Comment: Yes, I suppose I can. Your custom fields are probably shown after the username, password etc. input. This means they are inserted with either the hook woocommerce_register_form or register_form. The function which creates and therefore is responsible for your custom fields must use one of these 2 hooks. Are you now able to find the right function?