# Remove WooCommerce checkout fields values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to apply `autocomplete="off"` on my WooCommerce checkout fields but it just doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that for the checkout form?

I checked the docs and there's nothing available there. I also tried setting the default value to empty but it doesn't work either. This is when the user is not logged in of course.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried `unset` as suggested by @smvax but it did not work as well.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'default_values_checkout_fields');
function default_values_checkout_fields($fields) {
  if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
      unset($fields['billing_city']);
      unset($fields['billing_first_name']);
      unset($fields['billing_last_name']);
      unset($fields['billing_company']);
      unset($fields['billing_address_1']);
      unset($fields['billing_address_2']);
      unset($fields['billing_city']);
      unset($fields['billing_postcode']);
      unset($fields['billing_country']);
      unset($fields['billing_state']);
      unset($fields['billing_email']);
      unset($fields['billing_phone']);
      unset($fields['shipping_city']);
      unset($fields['shipping_first_name']);
      unset($fields['shipping_last_name']);
      unset($fields['shipping_company']);
      unset($fields['shipping_address_1']);
      unset($fields['shipping_address_2']);
      unset($fields['shipping_postcode']);
      unset($fields['shipping_country']);
      unset($fields['shipping_state']);
      return $fields;
  }
}
```

I also tried the answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582340/clear-checkout-fields-in-woocommerce)** but it's not working as well.

Thanks

Comment: Nkatry ka na nito jeepers?
 :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694355/registration-form-fields-reset-after-submit-wordpress-woocommerce

Comment: @smzvax I just tried `unset` and the whole form went missing.

Comment: how about adding **[‘clear’]** as shown here: https://surpriseazwebservices.com/edit-woocommerce-checkout-fields/

Comment: @jeepers_creepers, where are you adding the `AUTOCOMPLETE = "off"` attribute ?

Comment: @MayankRaj on the `<form>`

Comment: @smzvax does not work either :(

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Wordpress [**`'__return_empty_string'`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string) with [**`woocommerce_checkout_get_value`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#977) WooCommerce filter hook to get empty values simply this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_get_value','__return_empty_string', 1, 1);
```

> This will empty all checkout values, when checkout page is loaded.

*The Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

> You should reset all existing sessions in Woocommerce settings > System status > tools and also the cache if your e-commerce use any.
>   Also empty your browser cache and stored data.

Related: [Clear only some checkout fields values in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795010/clear-only-some-checkout-fields-values-in-woocommerce/50795611#50795611)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's not working when I tried it. I added it in my child theme's functions.php file. My checkout URL: http://dfp-dev.creativequoin.com/checkout/?v=4e45c2af0995

Comment: @jeepers_creepers I have tested this code on 3 different WooCommerce websites, and it works on all of them. So there is certainly some custom code in your theme or in a third party plugin, that is making a conflict… I have changed the priority in my hook (code). Try it again. I hope it will  work as it should. You can test it here on my raw test server: http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie/shop/ (shop something, then after your 1st order, add something to cart and go to checkout… you will see no data in checkout fields).

Comment: it worked when I added it on my custom Woocommerce plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set autocomplete="off" for the form fields using the woocommerce_checkout_fields filter.

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'autocomplete_off_checkout_fields');
    function autocomplete_off_checkout_fields($fields) {
          $fields['billing_first_name']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
          return $fields;
      }
    }
```

This will work on all the woocommerce checkout fields.

Comment: Note that Chrome browsers will intentionally ignore the "off" value and still apply autocompletion based on what the user has added to Chrome, i.e. payment data or addresses.