# Clear only some checkout fields values in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce i am trying to clear the checkout fields. so when a user that has ordered something before, and is now ordering something again, he/she will have to write in all his/her information again.

i am using this code

```
function clear_checkout_fields($input){
return '';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 'clear_checkout_fields' , 1);
```

Now this code is clearing all the fields, but it also changes my VAT to show as 0.

does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: @dipmala This question has nothing to do with the linked thread and it's not a duplicate.

Comment: What is the attribute `name` for your VAT custom checkout field please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some arguments errors in your `woocommerce_checkout_get_value` hooked function.
There is in fact 2 arguments:

- the `$value` argument that is returned as it is a filter hook,
- the `$imput` argument that you can use to target any checkout field.

So in your case you will use the `$imput` argument, to avoid your custom VAT checkout field to be emptied. In the code below, you will need to replace `vat_number` by the correct field `name` attribute that is set in your custom VAT checkout field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value' , 'clear_checkout_fields' , 10, 2 );
function clear_checkout_fields( $value, $input ){
    if( $input != 'vat_number' )
        $value = '';
    
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! One follow up question. How would you do this for multiple fields?

Comment: @StanleyTan You can do ist with in_array() function like : `if ( ! in_array( $input, array( 'vat_number', 'something' ) ) ) {` or `if ( in_array( $input, array( 'vat_number', 'something' ) ) ) {` depending on what you want…